# Warning message: In id == i : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to set up a loop which should give me 6 SEPERATE time series plots. However, I only get 1 plot which is quite strange. I get a warning message In id == i : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length. Any ideas? Thanks

```
#Importing data
    df <- read_csv("01_tracks.csv")
    
    #Preparing data 
    df1 <- filter(df,laneId == 5, width <= 6) #Filtering to only lane 5 and no trucks
    
    for(i in head(unique(select(df1,id)))) {
      print(i)
      veh <- filter(df1,id == i)
      timeplot <- ts(veh[,7],start = 1)
      plot(autoplot(timeplot) + ggtitle(i) + ylab("X Velocity"))

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would it be possible to provide a reproducible example?


  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Little hard to do without sample data, but I think you wrongfully believe that `i` is an integer here. I think this is wrong, though. `head(unique(select(df1,id)))` produces not a vector, but a one-column dataframe. And a dataframe is *a list of vectors* that is iterated over. So, I think there will be only one iteration.

If you do `pull(head(unique(select(df1,id))))` it might work.

(And actually `unique(df1$id)[1:6]` should do the same and looks nicer.)

Answer (score 0):

## dataframe

```
names <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

data <- c(2,6,8,1,3,6,3,4,3,8,6,5)

frame <- data.frame(data, names)
```

Using for-loops you can get individual plots, assign unique id to pdf to get individual plots.

```
for ( i in unique(frame$names)){
  pdf(i)
  plot (frame$data [frame$names == i], frame$names[frame$names == i])
  dev.off()
}
```